# C# LinkList nodes are not updating while deleting element from between of list

Tags: c#, data-structures, linked-list

```
public void DeleteBetween(int ele)
{

         if (IsEmpty()) 
         {
             Console.WriteLine("List is empty");
             return;
         }
         Node current = head;
         while (current.element != ele)
         {
             current = current.next;
             if (current.next == null)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("No such element exists");
                 return;
             }
         }
         int number = current.element;
         current = current.next; 
         if(head.element == number)
         {
             head = head.next;
         }
         if(IsEmpty())
         {
             tail = null;
         }
}
```

The code is fine for first and last element deletion but is not updating if the element is deleted from between of list, can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 0):

In the code, you wrote you are moving the `current` pointer to the next node without actually deleting the node. You are not updating the `next` node.

Try this code:

```cs
public void DeleteBetween(int ele)
{
    if (IsEmpty()) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("List is empty");
        return;
    }

    Node current = head;
    Node previous = null;

    while (current != null && current.Element != ele)
    {
        previous = current;
        current = current.Next;
    }

    if (current == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No such element exists");

        return;
    }

    if (previous == null)
    {
        head = head.Next;

        if (IsEmpty())
        {
            tail = null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        previous.Next = current.Next;

        if (current.Next == null)
        {
            tail = previous;
        }
    }
}
```